# How to update a property in a separate class from a child view and have the parent view update

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I'm using Xcode 12 and SwiftUI code and lifecycle.

I Couldn't find an answer to this when I searched here or on google but Im new to code and I may not really know what terms to search for. This is also my first post, I hope I'm doing it right.

I've tried to create a simplified version of what I'm trying to accomplish.

basically the goal is to have the text above the button in the ContentView change from "Title" to "Hello" when I press the button.  I know I can achieve this much more simply by placing the title variable in the ContentView struct, but for my purposes I really need it in a separate class.

Thanks in advance.

```
class Data: ObservableObject {
    @Published var title = "Title"
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var data = Data()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(data.title)
                .padding()
            ButtonView(data: $data.title) // I'm not sure if this line alone is the problem or if my thinking and code structuring is just all wrong.
        }
    }
}

struct ButtonView: View {
    @Binding var data: Data
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                data.title = "Hello"
            }, label: {
                Text("Button")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not use `Data` as it is already a standard swift name. Then try the following:

```
class Datax: ObservableObject {
    @Published var title = "Title"
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var data = Datax()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(data.title).padding()
            ButtonView(data: data)  // <-- here
        }
    }
}

struct ButtonView: View {
    @ObservedObject var data: Datax  // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                data.title = "Hello"
            }, label: {
                Text("Button")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! and such a quick response too.  I notice that the ObservedObject property wrapper was used in place of my Binding wrapper in the ButtonView.  I'm curious as to how it was not needed but I'm sure I'll pick up on these things eventually...  Anyway you're my hero!  Thanks again.  I've been trying to figure this out for some time!

Comment: Glad it helped. By and large (not always), `@Binding` works with `@State`  
and `@StateObject` works with `@ObservedObject`.